# Find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{x^4}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm solving a combinatorics problem using generating function and reached the following expression: $$\frac{x^4}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}$$

How can I expand it to find a general expression for the coefficient of $x^n$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would find the partial fraction of $\frac1{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: Can you show me how? I'm struggling with this technique.

Comment: This is not really different from your previous question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial fraction: $$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}=\frac1{8(1+x)}+\frac1{8(1-x)}+\frac1{4(1-x)^2}+\frac1{2(1-x)^3}$$

Taylor series: $$\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...$$$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$$ for $|x|<1$.

Hence $$\frac1{8(1+x)}+\frac1{8(1-x)}=\frac18(2+2x^2+2x^4+...)=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}$$$$\frac1{4(1-x)^2}+\frac1{2(1-x)^3}=\frac14((1+x+x^2+x^3+...)^2+2(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)^3)=\frac14\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+n)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+n)(2+n)x^n\right)=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+n)(3+n)x^n$$ So $$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[x^{2n}+(1+n)(3+n)x^n\right]$$ This means that $$\boxed{\frac{x^4}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[x^{4+2n}+(1+n)(3+n)x^{4+n}\right]\, \text{for} \,|x|<1}$$ Can you finish?

Comment: How can you make it a closed form?

Comment: Consider the cases when $n$ is odd and even. If $n$ is odd, then we only need to concentrate on $(1+n)(3+n)x^{4+n}$ since $x^{4+2n}$ is even. So coefficient of $x^{2k+1}$ for $k=2, 3, ...$ is $(1+k)(3+k)$ - why? Can you deal with the case when $n=2k$ for $k=2, 3, ...$?

Comment: @Leox Where is it wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry, everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$\frac{x^4}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n.
$$ 
Since the denominator has the form 
$$
(1-x^2)(1-x)^2=-{x}^{4}+2\,{x}^{3}-2\,x+1,
$$
then $a_n$ satisfied the following recurrence relation 
$$
a_n=2a_{n-1}-2a_{n-3}+a_{n-4},a_1=0,a_2=0,a_3=0,a_4=1.
$$
By solving it we get 
$$
a_n=\frac 3 8-\frac 7 4\,n+\frac 1 8\, \left( -1 \right) ^{n}+\frac 1 2\, \left( n+1 \right)  \left( \frac 1 2\,n+1 \right).
$$